# Regex: Matching all words in a phrase

Tags: c#, regex, string, smalltalk, pharo

Is this possible?

For a sentence such as `hello how are you`, I'd like my regular expression to return `hello` `how` `are` `you`. It only ever returns just `hello` and not the other words.

My Regex:

```
[A-Za-z]*
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
If it matters, I'm using Pharo Smalltalk. I've been testing in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need split the sentence by spaces this can be done using `string.Split()` method:

```
var s = "hello how are you";
var words = s.Split();
```

If you want to use regular expressions:

```
var s = "hello how are you";
var regex = "\\w+";
var words = Regex.Matches(s, regex).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, a regex engine can't return multiple matches itself, so it depends on the classes you can use within the programming language?

Comment: @KingDan: each programming language defines its regex syntax (mainly PCRE). The way you can use depends on the classes/functions that were implemented for it

Comment: Damn, so I think I've run into a Smalltalk issue then. I'm able to get this working properly in C#. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope, not a smalltalk issue. Your regex doesn't match more than hello

Comment: @StephanEggermont: my code is in C#, I just ran and gave me the 4 words.

Comment: Yours yes, the one from the question?

Comment: @StephanEggermont: I never used smalltalk, but probably there will be a function to find all matches.

Answer (score 7):

Also in Pharo send the `#substrings` message:

```
'Hello how are you' substrings
```

and get the array:

```
#('Hello' 'how' 'are' 'you').
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find a chapter about Regex in Pharo here:

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/view/Books/job/DeepIntoPharo/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/tmp/PBE2.pdf

I you just want to split the string on the spaces you can just run:

`Character space split: 'My String To split'`

You will get an OrderedCollection with all the words.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Regex in this case at all. Simply use `Split`.

```
string str = "hello how are you";
string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
```

In case you really really want the Regex too much, `\w+` as Regex captures any word. So in C# the Regex should look like this `string regex = "\\w+"` if you need at least word.

- The `\w` stands for any word including characters as
- The `+` quantifier stands for **at least one time**
- The `*` quantifier stands for **zero or more times**

Answer (score 2):

The standard tries to match, which it doesn't because there are spaces

```
matcher := RxMatcher forString: '[A-Za-z]*'.
matcher matches: 'hello how are you'

false
```

If you ask for all matches it tells you there are 5, because * also matches zero characters

```
matcher := RxMatcher forString: '[A-Za-z]*'.
matcher matchesIn: 'hello how are you'

"an OrderedCollection('hello' 'how' 'are' 'you' '')"
```

And for the wanted result you might try

```
matcher := RxMatcher forString: '[A-Za-z]+'.
matcher matchesIn: 'hello how are you'

"an OrderedCollection('hello' 'how' 'are' 'you')"
```

and if you want to know how long the words are you can do

```
matcher := RxMatcher forString: '[A-Za-z]+'.
matcher matchesIn: 'hello how are you' collect: [ :each | each size ]

"an OrderedCollection(5 3 3 3)"
```